# Implement escrow like functionality using stripe connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, escrow

I'm working on a feature which requires following flow

- client will send payment to platform.
- After x amount of time on specific event
- platform will send amount to seller.
  Just like fiverr payment works. The default is to hold payment in platform but the limit is 90 days.
  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I recommend looking at the [separate charges and transfers documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers), which outlines the Connect flow you're describing.

Comment: I have already read that documentation but as I have mentioned earlier the maximum time to hold payment is 90 days.. but I want to hold payment for x amount of time which is why the default might not work. Kindly correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Correct, 90 days is the limit as per the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-balances#holding-funds). Outside of that, I'd recommend speaking with Stripe support. This is not a developer related or technical question.